# perl, awk parsing log file

Tags: perl, logging, awk

Can someone help me with the log file to convert them from vertical to horizontal?

I have this `file1.txt`

```
Time: 2018070515
timezone: CEST
Client: 192.168.205.132
Subscriber: 345896546
proxyIP: 100.24.201.102
device: Android

Time: 2018070516
timezone: CEST
Client: 192.168.205.134
Subscriber: 345777546
proxyIP: 100.24.202.102
device: Android

Time: 2018070516
timezone: CEST
Start: 1530
Client: 192.168.204.112
Subscriber: 345898646
proxyIP: 100.24.202.102
device: Android

Time: 2018070517
timezone: CEST
Start: 1530
Client: 192.168.205.137
Subscriber: 345897466
proxyIP: 100.24.201.102
device: IPhone
```

and I need to have them in this way:

```
2018070515,192.168.205.132,345896546,Android
2018070516,192.168.205.134,345777546,Android
2018070516,192.168.204.112,345898646,Android
2018070517,192.168.205.137,345897466,IPhone
```

the number of row is not costant, I know that they start with Time.

Thanks you all, for the given solutions. But my file logs has more than 100000 row, and any solution that I try give mi error of output. When I use file as the example that I put here, the command work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Perl one liner

```
perl -an00E 'BEGIN{ $" = "," } %F = @F; say "@F{qw(Time: Client: Subscriber: device:)}"' <./file.txt
```

`-00` reads in the file using blank lines as the input record separator

`-n` loops over each record in the file

`-a` auto splits the record into `@F`

Then the code makes a hash from `@F` and prints out the required records having set `$"` to place a `,` between each element of an interpolated array or slice

Note that this assumes there are no spaces in the data

Comment: thank you , it was good solutions. But my file logs has more than 100000 row, and any solution that I try give mi error of output. When I use file as the example that I put here, the command work.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat your data like YAML, because it's simple key/value pairs separated by colons `:`.

This Perl solution will set the input record separator [`$/`](https://perldoc.pl/variables/$/) to two new lines (we assume Linux line endings here) and treat each record as an actual record. It will then use [Perl's YAML parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod) to convert it to a hash reference that you can then selectively join into your CSV file.

```
use v5.10; # strict, warnings, feature 'say'
use YAML 'Load';

local $/ = "\n\n";
while (my $record = <DATA>) {
    my $fields = Load($record);
    say join ',', @$fields{qw/Time Client Subscriber device/};
}

__DATA__
Time: 2018070515
timezone: CEST
Client: 192.168.205.132
Subscriber: 345896546
proxyIP: 100.24.201.102
device: Android

Time: 2018070516
timezone: CEST
Client: 192.168.205.134
Subscriber: 345777546
proxyIP: 100.24.202.102
device: Android
```

If your records may not contain all required fields you can use a [`map`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/map) and the [*defined-or* operator](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Logical-Defined-Or) `//` to get an empty string instead.

```
say join ',', map { $foo->{$_} // q{} } qw/Time Client Subscriber device/;
```

This solution requires at least Perl 5.10 for [`say`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/say).

It can be converted to a one-liner easily.

```
$ perl -MYAML -nE 'BEGIN { $/ = "\n\n" } $f = Load($_); say join ",", @$f{qw/Time Client Subscriber device/}' <inputfile
```

Note that you may need to install YAML from CPAN.

Comment: Please note that this is more a TIMTOWTDI demonstration than a viable solution. It works, but there are easier ways. Treat it like a nudge to once in a while think outside the box.

Comment: Thanks it works, but my file has more then 100000 row, so for my case give error.

Comment: @albi both my solution as well as the other solution use processing on a record basis. What error do you see? I guess your file does not have a consistent format. The length of the file should only matter in terms of how long the program runs. A few hundred thousand records is not a prow. Obviously my solution is going to be very slow with that amount. It's not meant to be used, more like a cheeky demonstration.

Comment: can we talk in private? so I can send you some log?

Comment: @albi I'm sorry, that's not how stackoverflow.com works. You have already gotten several solutions for free without showing any effort of your own. If you would like to get personal help with this you'll have to hire someone. That's not the purpose of the site though. I answered your question because I was curious if that problem would be solvable in the way I suggested. I'm still curious, but the whole idea here is to help future visitors so I'm afraid I can't help you in a private way.

Comment: you're really right, I have some problems with my log file, which are so different. I will try, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could try this `awk` command:

```
awk -v RS= 'BEGIN{r["Time:"];r["Client:"];r["Subscriber:"];r["device:"]}
    {for(i = 1; i <= NF; i+=2) {
       if($i in r) {
           if(i != NF-1) {f=","} else {f=""} printf "%s%s" ,$(i+1),f
       }
     }
     print ""
    }' file1.txt
```

**Options used**:

- `-v RS=`: converts each paragraph in a record.
- `r`: is an array with fields needed.
- `for` and `if($1 in r)`: loops through the fields, and if the field `i` is in `r` then print it.
- `if(i!=NF)` and `else` is just for formatting.

**EDIT**

It only works if value only has one string.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'll edit my answer to specify that only works if the value field only has one string. I'll apply changes according your feedback too, thanks!

Comment: Thanks it works, but my file has more then 100000 row, so for my case give error

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -00 -nE '$text = $_; say join ",", map {$text =~ /$_: (.*)/} qw<Time Client Subscriber device>' file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but my file has more then 100000 row, so for my case give error

Comment: The number of rows should not cause an error, because `-00` and `-n` switches make Perl process only one paragraph in memory at a time. What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array that maps each tag/name to it's value and then every time you hit a blank line or the end of file print the values for the tags from the preceding record that you're interested in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF {
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/^[^:]+: */,"",val)
    f[tag] = val
    next
}
{ prt() }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    OFS = ","
    print f["Time"], f["Client"], f["Subscriber"], f["device"]
    delete f
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2018070515,192.168.205.132,345896546,Android
2018070516,192.168.205.134,345777546,Android
2018070516,192.168.204.112,345898646,Android
2018070517,192.168.205.137,345897466,IPhone
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.